# How can I create my own %FOLDERNAME% links?

Tags: windows

For example you can type into the windows searchbar/run window %appdata% and it takes you straight to your C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData folder (on windows 7) How can I make my own links likes this? Also how do I edit existing links like that to go to a different directory?

I am assuming its some kind of thing like mklink, or just a list in some file somewhere. What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that environment variables do the trick, at least under Windows 7. E.g. I have created a user environment variable `REF2Root` with value `C:\Ref2`. (See [Serious' answer](https://superuser.com/questions/361030/how-can-i-create-my-own-foldername-links/361033#361033) for a description of how to do that.) If I now press the Windows key to open the start menu and type `%REF2Root%` the system opens an explorer window for `C:\Ref2`.

Comment: So In the advanced system properties (when right clicking on my computer) I should be able edit these in the environment variables window? Appdata doesn't seem to be in there so I cant edit that and putting it in manually seemed to fail, hopefully it will work for other links though, thanks! (Can't vote you up but I would if I could)

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer (hopefully).

Comment: If you want you can [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Done because you were first, even no pretty pictures :P

Answer (score 2):

Add a new environment variable for example:
variable name: mypath
variable value: D:\songs

Now you can type %mypath% in run and access the songs folder.
[image]

Comment: +1 - no new content :-P but nice pictures.

Comment: Someone else gave the answer while I was writing . I need to be quicker :-)

Comment: +1 indeed, but if I wanted to edit special system ones such as APPDATA

Comment: I have found out how to do that now though, through regedit -> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders and then the system name you like

Comment: I'm not sure if changing %appdata% etc is a good idea. I guess quite a lot of stuff depends on it pointing to the "real" directory.

Comment: It is probably a bad idea, but my %appdata% links to appdata/roaming which was annoying me, since it shouldve have just linked to appdata